# Asymptotic Distribution Using CLT

Tags: self-study, asymptotics, central-limit-theorem, sampling-distribution

I have random variables $X_1, X_2, ... , X_n \sim \text{IID } f_X$ using the density function:

$$f_X(x) = \frac{2x}{\theta^2} \cdot \mathbb{I}(0 \leqslant x \leqslant \theta).$$

I have to use the central limit theorem to derive the asymptotic distribution of the sample mean $\bar{X}_n$.

Comment: You tagged this as [tag:nonparametric]. What do you see as nonparametric?

Comment: I tagged it as nonparametric because it said that I can use that tag for parametric and nonparametric discussion. I'm kinda new here hehe so I can't create new tag.. there's no parametric tag

Comment: If you want an answer to a self-study question, you need to tell us what you have already tried to solve your problem, and where you are stuck.

Comment: Hello, I think I was also to solve it already. I found that you just have to get the expectation of X and X^2 to get the mean and variance of the distribution, then just apply CLT. Thank you for the help in formatting my question. I look forward in posting more queries in statistics here!